# Creating an expression for use with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following method that starts an `IQueryable`.

```
public static IQueryable<StorageDetail> QueryStorageDetails(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, DateRange dateRange)
{
    return from detail in dbContext.StorageDetails
           where (detail.ArrivalDate != null && detail.ArrivalDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
                (detail.ReleaseDate == null || detail.ReleaseDate >= dateRange.StartDate)) ||
                (detail.TakeOrPayStartDate != null && detail.TakeOrPayStartDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
                (detail.TakeOrPayEndDate == null || detail.TakeOrPayEndDate >= dateRange.StartDate))
           select detail;
}
```

I tried to refactor it as follows.

```
public static bool FilterByDate(StorageDetail detail, DateRange dateRange)
{
    return (detail.ArrivalDate != null && detail.ArrivalDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
        (detail.ReleaseDate == null || detail.ReleaseDate >= dateRange.StartDate)) ||
        (detail.TakeOrPayStartDate != null && detail.TakeOrPayStartDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
        (detail.TakeOrPayEndDate == null || detail.TakeOrPayEndDate >= dateRange.StartDate));
}

public static IQueryable<StorageDetail> QueryStorageDetails(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, DateRange dateRange)
{
    return dbContext.StorageDetails
        .Where(d => FilterByDate(d, dateRange));
}
```

But this produces an error.

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<StorageDetail>
    .Where(s => QueryHelper.FilterByDate(
        detail: s, 
        dateRange: __dateRange_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this, possibly by creating an `Expression` but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: In the latest version of entity framework, all expression should be written in a way that they can be directly translated into their SQL equivalents. That said, even a `FirstOrDefault` within a LINQ query may lead to similar errors now.

Comment: @Transcendent: Not sure you understand the question. The first query works fine so my expression is okay. I just want a way to construct it so I can pass it as a separate expression rather than a compiled function.

Comment: Yea I exactly got your point, this part `FilterByDate` makes it fail, because the framework is no longer able to translate this. In other words it cannot call the method and create the expression tree out of it anymore.

Comment: @Transcendent: It can't process it because it's a compiled method. That's why I need to create an `Expression` from the same code.

Comment: Well, creating Expression Trees manually in such way that would work for you is a bit tricky, I will try to provide an example as an answer but I can't promise as I'm pretty busy. Though, it can be done by playing with `Expression` type. I can remember I once wrote a method that could create such Expressions from parameters passed as query string to a URL.

Comment: @Transcendent: I could've sworn I saw a way to do this without manually building the tree. Still looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterByDate` should return `Expression<Func<StorageDetail, bool>>` so EF would be able to translate your code into query. Try something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<StorageDetail, bool>> FilterByDate(DateRange dateRange)
{
    return detail => (detail.ArrivalDate != null && detail.ArrivalDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
        (detail.ReleaseDate == null || detail.ReleaseDate >= dateRange.StartDate)) ||
        (detail.TakeOrPayStartDate != null && detail.TakeOrPayStartDate <= dateRange.EndDate &&
        (detail.TakeOrPayEndDate == null || detail.TakeOrPayEndDate >= dateRange.StartDate));
}
```

And

```
public static IQueryable<StorageDetail> QueryStorageDetails(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, DateRange dateRange)
{
    return dbContext.StorageDetails
        .Where(FilterByDate(dateRange));
}
```